# Push modified file back to git without fetching

Tags: github

I create a git, pushed a file to it, TempMonitorGPRS.ino from my mac.

I tested the code, got some logs that I wanted to save.  So I copied the log results and created a file, manually, in my repo.  I made some changes to the .ino file which I want to push back to the repo from my mac.  But when I try to git push -u origin master, I get a warning that I need to git pull first to get those files that I created manually, into my local mac.  I dont want to get those files.  Is there any way for me to continue pushing changes to my .ino file without ever getting those files onto my local computer?

Comment: Git doesn't push files; it's not a file sync tool. Roughly speaking, it moves around tree objects which are collections of files. If your local repo's head commit has one file in it on the branch you're on, and you push that to the remote branch, then the remote repo will also have one file on that branch head.

Comment: Ok so I can't push just one file onto the repo without first pulling back the manually added files on the repo?

Comment: If the remote repo has added some files and commited them to the branch, and you locally add a file and do the same thing, then the branches are out of sync. If you  push  that, it will be rejected. If you force it through  which a `push -f` (which the remote might not be configured to permit) then you will clobber their branch with your change; their commit will be detached and yours will take its place, resulting in just one file.